# Encompassing same subset of column headers under N number of parent column headers Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to have a 2d array of size 52x40 be made into a dataframe of 52x40 but with only 10 column headers. In the sample below, lets say a dataframe of size 52x30 to have 10 columns headers that encompass 3 columns each.

I have been trying to look at pandas documentation　and other similar problem fixes that aren't at all that similar but still, tried and failed.

Anyone have any idea how to do this? 
Right now the closest implementation I can do is to receive a 52x40 pandas dataframe but with the column headers being 4 times of the same day, then the next day repeated 4 times, then the next etc... until 10 days have been done. 
Ie: 40 columns in total.

```
final_logic_table = pd.DataFrame(final_logic_table, index=[nurseData.importShift.columns], columns=[dates]);
        final_logic_table.set_index(numpy.unique(dates));
        final_logic_table.sort_index(inplace=True);
```

**Here's what I am trying to achieve:**

[image: sample]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC03r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
np.random.seed(1256)

dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-12', periods=10)
c= pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, ['Morning','Afternoon','Night']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(52,30)), columns=c)
print (df.head())

  2018-01-12                 2018-01-13                 2018-01-14            \
     Morning Afternoon Night    Morning Afternoon Night    Morning Afternoon   
0          1         5     8          8         9     3          6         3   
1          0         7     2          8         2     4          8         3   
2          6         9     4          2         8     7          1         6   
3          1         8     9          1         6     3          4         9   
4          7         8     7          0         6     3          0         2   

        2018-01-15  ...  2018-01-18 2018-01-19                 2018-01-20  \
  Night    Morning  ...       Night    Morning Afternoon Night    Morning   
0     0          6  ...           4          9         4     6          1   
1     5          5  ...           2          4         7     4          0   
2     3          2  ...           3          2         4     1          5   
3     1          3  ...           0          2         1     3          7   
4     0          7  ...           8          2         1     5          0   

                  2018-01-21                  
  Afternoon Night    Morning Afternoon Night  
0         7     7          5         8     3  
1         4     9          6         0     4  
2         4     9          5         2     4  
3         4     8          1         0     2  
4         3     9          1         7     1  

[5 rows x 30 columns]
```

Comment: Edit: ah, forgive me. Seems I made a mistake with setting the column index's to be a 2d vs 1d array.

Comment: @RobRen - Yes, this way working MultiIndex. do you need something else?

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thank you; changed a quick thing about your method but it works great.